# Use SSHFS on XenServer 6.1

Tags: backup, virtual-machines, xen, sshfs

On Xen Server 6.1, to backup my VMs, I use a script based on the following tools:

- `xe vm-list` to build a list of the VMs to backup
- `xe vm-snapshot` to take a snapshot of the VMs
- `xe template-param-set is-a-template=false ha-always-run=false` to convert the snapshot to a VM
- `xe vm-export vm=uuid_of_this_new_vm filename=|ssh ..... "cat > /path/backup.xva"`
  --> To send the export to my backup server without to store it locally
- `xe vm-uninstall`

I'd like to use sshfs to mount my remote backup server on my Xen host. But sshfs is not available in the Xen distribution or the default repository (XenServer 6.1.0 updates).

I have a few possibilities to install sshfs on my Xen host:

- I add a repo that contains sshfs. I think it could cause me troubles later. It's not supported by Xen and I prefer to let the host config mostly unchanged
- I could take a tarball and install it in a directory apart
- or I take a RPM and install it apart

OR I find a way to pipe a remote ssh command into `xe vm-import` like I do for the export. I tested a lot of things but nothing that works

What would be the best solution in your opinion?

Comment: You need a more secure way to get your cloned vms to your backup server, correct?

Comment: I would be nice :) ... Either ssh or sshfs I think

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old question, I have just figured this one out myself.

First.. what DOES NOT WORK (All tested on XenServer 6.5):

`xe-import filename=/dev/stdin` **does not work.. at all.**  It does not matter whether you do:

```
# simple local import on xenhost
xe vm-import filename=/dev/stdin < myexport.xva

# try it the other way, with cat, still won't work:    
cat myexport.xva | xe vm-import filename=/dev/stdin

# and no, dd instead of cat in the above does not make it better

# nor can you pull the file from elsewhere via ssh:
ssh user@backupserver "cat myexport.xva" |  xe vm-import filename=/dev/stdin

# nor the other way, pushing from elsewhere to your xenserver
ssh root@xenhost "xe vm-import filename=/dev/stdin" < myexport.xva

# named pipes don't work either, even locally:
mkfifo mypipe
cat myexport.xva > ./mypipe &
xe vm-import filename=./mypipe
```

**So, what I have found is that there is no way to import from a stream, it has to be a real filesystem of some sort.  Apparently this used to work, but it doesn't now.**  My guess is that xenserver wants to seek.

(If anyone can spot a flaw in my attempts and prove me wrong, I'd be very grateful).

So, yes, my conclusion is that you must use a remote filesystem, and we know that NFS works for this, because we've used it.. but decided on sshfs for simplicity.  Here is how I installed sshfs on XenServer 6.5:

```
# fuse-fs and fuse-libs are in existing repos, so..
yum --enablerepo=base --disablerepo=citrix install fuse-fs
# for some reason yum wanted to install i386 fuse-libs which fails
# because of a dependency on i386 glibc.. nevermind all that, tell it
# directly that we want x86_64 and it will work:
yum --enablerepo=base --disablerepo=citrix install fuse-libs.x86_64

# fuse-sshfs is in the epel repo, which we need to add
yum --disablerepo=citrix --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
# now install fuse-sshfs
yum --disablerepo=citrix --enablerepo=extras install fuse-sshfs

# The above leaves epel-release enabled, which should be no problem but
# nevertheless I disabled it since I don't need it anymore:
#   Use vim to edit /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
#   Where it says `enabled=1` change to `enabled=0`
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Ok now to restore from an export on another machine:

```
# make mount point
mkdir backups

# mount location of your backups onto mount point
sshfs user@backupserver.mydomain.com:/path/to/backups backups

# import as usual
xe vm-import filename=backups/myexport.xva

# unmount the remote filesystem, if you don't need it anymore
umount backups

# IT WORKS
```

Oh, and I should add.. I tried installing the xenxerver tools on our backup server.. it does not work either.  Sure, you can execute commands and it all looks great.  But `filename=/dev/stdin` still does not work, NOR DOES `filename=/path/to/myexport.xva`.  It just hangs or starts importing then fails in weird ways.

So that's importing.. but what about exporting?  Using the xenserver tools remotely installed:

xe vm-export uuid=the-vm-uuid filename= -s xenhost.my.domain -u root -pwf password_file

This DOES export to stdout.  But it's a bit unclear as to whether those exports will always import successfully.  I experienced a couple of failures and some successes.  SO decided against using remote tools at all.. but do it via ssh instead:

```
ssh root@xenhost.my.domain "vm-export uuid=the-vm-uuid filename=" > myexport.xva
```

IT WORKS!

The upshot of this is that, with our backup system (Bareos) it is possible to do a backup via ssh directly into the backup software, without having to do an export to a temporary file first.  But to do the restore, it is necessary to restore the xva to a temporary storage first, then mount on the xenhost with sshfs, then vm-import.  I am sad that we can't stream both ways.. hopefully this will be fixed in xe some time.

Hope this helps some people.. it took a good amount of trial and error to test all the possibilities :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a way to import your xva-backups into XenServer, you can simply install the xe guest utilities onto your backup server. They are included in the xentools iso (linux folder). then you can use " xe -s serverip -u root -pw password vm-import..." to import your backups (or even export them).

Btw: Connection is secured via SSL.

Comment: I can't find a good doc about these parameters (-s , -u, -pw). I'd like to avoid clear password. Isn't it possible to use key authentication?

Comment: there's just "xe <command> [-s server] [-pw passwd] [-p port] [-u user] [-pwf password-file]!". after that you can type in the usual commands (e.g. vm-list). I don't know a way to avoid cleartext password by now. Example: "xe -s 192.168.0.0 -u root -pw passwort vm-shutdown vm=TestVM"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Task: Move VM from old XS to new XS
From: XS 6.2 70446c
To: XS 7.0 125380c

On XS 6.2 host i use this command in console:

`xe vm-export uuid=<VM_UUID> filename= | ssh root@<XS7_IP_ADDRESS> 'xe vm-import filename=/dev/stdin sr-uuid=<XS7_LOCAL_STORAGE_UUID>'`

All works great!